# Automapper. Error when try to map Nested Type

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm trying to map one object to another:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ShippingAddressModel, ShippingAddress>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Addresses.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.Name));
```

But I have an error:

> Expression 'x => x.Addresses.Name' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.

Comment: You should CreateMap for Addresses and let the automapper take care of mapping the Addresses property in ShippingAddress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<ShippingAddressModel, ShippingAddress>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Addresses, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model));
Mapper.CreateMap<ShippingAddressModel, Addresses>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.Name));
```